# If Statement inside Case Statement (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am new in coding at Visual studio.
I'm Using Visual Studio 2012
I Have a Question.
I want to Connect combobox and textbox31 to textbox1
ex. if the combobox is 100 and textbox31 is 1 so the textbox1 will be 100

I End Up With This Code:

```
Dim c As String

    c = ComboBox1.Text


    Select Case "c"

        Case 100
            If TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 100
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 75
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 50
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 0

            End If

        Case 75
            If TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
                TextBox31.Text = 75
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text >= 2.5 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 75
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 50
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 0

            End If

        Case 50
            If TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 50
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 50
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 50
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 0

            End If


        Case 25
            If TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 0

            End If

    End Select
```

but when i iput in combobox and textbox 31 the textbox1 didnt respond or what i want to get.

Comment: `Select Case "c"` is incorrect. It should be `Select Case c`

Comment: i just remove the "" i all the same.

Comment: This is VB.net not VBA if you're using Visual Studio. Check your variable types. I think with VB.net you can rely on it casting for you but it's good to be aware you're comparing c as String with Case 100 as Integer.

Comment: okay sorry i am new here.
thanks for reply
i'll update if anything comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you're using there is nested a bit more than I'd normally be comfortable with. In this instance you could consider something more like this:

```
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim aintValues() As Integer = {0, 25, 50, 75, 100}

    If IsNumeric(ComboBox1.Text) And IsNumeric(TextBox31.Text) Then
        c = ComboBox1.Text
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If c <= 25 Then
        aintValues = {0, 25, 25, 25, 25}
    ElseIf c <= 50 Then
        aintValues = {0, 25, 50, 50, 50}
    ElseIf c <= 75 Then
        aintValues = {0, 25, 50, 75, 75}
    End If

    If TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = aintValues(0)
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3.0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = aintValues(1)
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
        TextBox1.Text = aintValues(2)
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
        TextBox1.Text = aintValues(3)
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = aintValues(4)
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 42
    Else
        ' negative
    End If
```

Or you can still use a select case as follows:

```
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim aintValues() As Integer = {0, 25, 50, 75, 100}

    If IsNumeric(ComboBox1.Text) And IsNumeric(TextBox31.Text) Then
        c = ComboBox1.Text
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If c <= 25 Then
        aintValues = {0, 25, 25, 25, 25}
    ElseIf c <= 50 Then
        aintValues = {0, 25, 50, 50, 50}
    ElseIf c <= 75 Then
        aintValues = {0, 25, 50, 75, 75}
    End If

    Select Case TextBox31.Text
        Case Is >= 3.25
            TextBox1.Text = aintValues(0)
        Case Is >= 3.0
            TextBox1.Text = aintValues(1)
        Case Is >= 2.75
            TextBox1.Text = aintValues(2)
        Case Is >= 2.5
            TextBox1.Text = aintValues(3)
        Case Is >= 2.25
            TextBox1.Text = aintValues(4)
        Case Is >= 0
            TextBox1.Text = 42
        Case Else
            ' negative
    End Select
```

Comment: I Tried This Also it also 
but i adjusted the values of `Textbox31.Text` from 2.25 to 1, 2.5 to 2.25 and so on

but i dont understand much the code.
how its been done.

thanks i try to understand so i have new knowlegde .
:)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues with your code, but one place to start would be to understand that your conditional

```
Case 100
    If TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 100
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 75
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 50
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 25
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 0
    End If
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
Case 100
    If TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 100
    End If
```

the other conditions will never be tested because if `TextBox31.Text` is any value greater than or equal to `2.25` then it passes and we're done.

Addressing this problem, you might reverse the order of your conditions, i.e.

```
Case 100
    If TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 0
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 25
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 50
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 75
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 100
    End If
```

Additionally, it sounds like you'd like to cover the situation in which `TextBox31.Text < 2.25` which you could do with an `Else`

```
Case 100
    If TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 0
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 25
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 50
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 75
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 100
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = 100000
    End If
```

Comment: Mr.sfletche
`Case 100
    If TextBox31.Text >= 3.25 Then
        TextBox31.Text = 0
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 25
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 50
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 75
    ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
        TextBox1.Text = 100
    End If`

nothing Happens

Comment: @HarryReyes: that may be because `TextBox31.Text` does not contain a value >= 2.25 (in which case it does nothing)

Comment: i just edit now but nothing.

i just want to do
the `ComboBox1.Text` is previous scholarship percentage
then the `Textbox31.Text` is the grade.
the `Textbox1.Text` is the new scholarship percentage he/she will get

heres What I Want To do
when the previous scholarship percentage is 100 and the grade will not go down to 2.25 the new scholarship percentage maintain but if the grade is below 2.25 the new scholarship percentage will decrease to 75

Comment: @HarryReyes: i'm having a hard time following you, but it sounds like you might want to add an `Else` (see updated answer)

Comment: sorry i think its okay now i am testing it now

Comment: @Hawiie13 that tells me that `Textbox31.Text` is always less than 2.25

Comment: this what happen now i try the `else` the 100 `combobox1.text`< = `textbox31.text` 2.25 is `textbox1.text`  equals 100000 instead of `textbox1.text` equals to 100

Comment: `Textbox1.Text` will only be assigned 100 when `Textbox31.Text` is some value x, where `2.25 <= x < 2.5`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your script is about, but one thing could be your failure:

The first if..then-statement sets the text of TextBox31 instead of TextBox1.
I rather would write:

```
If TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
     TextBox1.Text = 100
```

Comment: my code is about
the `ComboBox1.Text` is previous scholarship percentage
then the `Textbox31.Text` is the grade.
the `Textbox1.Text` is the new scholarship percentage he/she will get

heres What I Want To do
when the previous scholarship percentage is 100 and the grade will not go down to 2.25 the new scholarship percentage maintain but if the grade is below 2.25 the new scholarship percentage will decrease to 75 and so on

Answer (score 0):

I Solve Now The Problem
i Use This Code:

```
Case 100
            If TextBox31.Text >= 3 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 0
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.75 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 25
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.5 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 50
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 2.25 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 75
            ElseIf TextBox31.Text >= 1 Then
                TextBox1.Text = 100
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = 0
```

Thanks Mr.sfletche For Not Giving up helping me.
Same With Other who help me thanyo very much
Mr.sfletche if i have other problems regarding this would you help me in fute

thanks alot guys

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of mathematical Sequences. You must not use if statement here. If so, you'll go insane when to work to revise is happened unfortunately.

```
    'Example Data
    Dim c = "50"
    Dim Text = "3.12"

    Dim value As Double
    Double.TryParse(Text, value)

    Dim num = Math.Ceiling((3.25 - value) / 0.25)

    Console.WriteLine(Math.Min(Integer.parseInt(c), 25 * num))
```

I assume that all you want to do is the above.